# Accept all vlan tagged traffic on interface

Tags: network-interface, vlan

I have the following setup. It is an ongoing setup to migrate my network in seperate vlan.

My issue is I cannot contact the ubuntu server from my laptop while connecting of wifi_admin(vlan10) but I can contact any device on wifi_iot(untagged)

I suppose I could solve this by creating an interface on ubuntu_server on top of LAN with (vlan10) or I eventually could configure the port of the switch as untagged. But I wanted to know if there is a way to accept all vlan tagged traffic on interface LAN on ubuntu_server.

The setup:

- ubuntu_server:
  interface LAN: 10.90.1.1
  dhcpd for net1 with range 10.90.1.100-200
- firewall (pfsense):
  interface LAN: 10.90.1.2
  interface ADMINS10 (vlan 10 on LAN)
  dhcpd for net2 with range 10.90.10.100-200
  rules are now allow in every directions
- wifi access point (unifi): apply vlan tagged depending on the ssid

  - ssid: wifi_admin (ADMIN = tagged 10)
    my laptop
  - ssid: wifi_iot (IOT = untagged)
    several iot devices
- managed "dumb" switch: no configuration applied on vlan, connect everything together

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details and context to your question. Are we talking about some kind of network appliance, like a switch or a PC and what would be the distribution? It's not really clear what your problem is, and what you have attempted so far.

Comment: I suppose the question is what you'd like to do with the traffic? Accept it for processing in the normal network stack as if it was untagged? Ok, but would you then send any replies back using untagged frames, and would that be any use? Or something else, but what? Also, any ways of doing that probably depend highly on the OS.